# Multiple regresssion K-S test in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, distributions, multiple-regression

As suggested, this question first appeared on SO but was now merged across to CV

So we can run a K-S test to assess if we have a difference in the distribution of two datasets, as outlined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test).

So lets take the following data

```
set.seed(123)
N <- 1000
var1 <- runif(N, min=0, max=0.5)
var2 <- runif(N, min=0.3, max=0.7)
var3 <- rbinom(n=N, size=1, prob = 0.45)

df <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3)

We can then seperate based on var3 outcome

df.1 <- subset(df, var3 == 1)
df.2 <- subset(df, var3 == 0)
```

Now we can run a Kolmogorov–Smirnov test to test for differences in the distributions of each individual variable.

```
ks.test(jitter(df.1$var1), jitter(df.2$var1))
ks.test(jitter(df.1$var2), jitter(df.2$var2))
```

And not suprisngly, we do not get a difference and can assume the different dataset have been drawn from the same distribution. This can be visualised through:

```
plot(ecdf(df.1$var1), col=2)
    lines(ecdf(df.2$var1))

plot(ecdf(df.1$var2), col=3)
    lines(ecdf(df.2$var2), col=4)
```

But now we want to consider if the distributions between var3==0 and var3==1 differ when we consider both `var1` & `var2` together. **Is there an R package to run such a test when we have a multiple predictors**

The similar question was posed [here](http://www.inside-r.org/questions/multivariate-kolmogorov-smirnov-distance-r), but has not received any answers

There appears to be some literature: [Example 1](http://v-scheiner.brunel.ac.uk/bitstream/2438/1166/1/acat2007.pdf) [Example 2](http://halweb.uc3m.es/esp/Personal/personas/dpena/articles/kolpl97.pdf)

But nothing appears to be linked to R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than running a KS test, you can use a [kernel two-sample test](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume13/gretton12a/gretton12a.pdf) based on the maximum mean discrepancy (MMD). The basic variant is implemented in [the `kmmd` function of the `kernlab` pafkage](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/kernlab/docs/Asymbound).

If your sample size is very large, there are [variants](http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.04725) which are much faster and not particularly hard to implement.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Dougal. In theory the test seems to make sense. However in the package release notes, the example provided is very very simplistic and the link to the paper, is very mathematical deep!! As I am new to kernel theory, I am not sure how I can relate this to my problem. Have you used this test before and based on a sample dataset could you offer some guidance. Thanks

Comment: @lukeg I'm traveling currently, but will try to put something together in a few days.

Comment: are you able to put together a short example @Dougal?

Comment: @lukeg Sorry, I totally lost track of making an example. Did you figure it out?

Comment: not really, would be great if you could throw something together or guide me towards something

Comment: Okay. I'll do something with examples soon.